# OpenCL global_id starts count from 1 instead of 0. Xeon Phi

Tags: opencl

I am a novice at OpenCL and recently I have stumbled onto something which does not make sense to me.

I am using Intel drivers (working on linux machine) and the device is Xeon Phi coprocessor.

The problem is that when I give `local_item_size` as an argument to

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,
                       forceKernel, 1, 
                       &localItemSize, &globalItemSize,
                       NULL, 0, NULL, &kernelDone);
```

and when printing global thread id in the kernel

```
int tid = get_global_id(0);
```

The thread ids start from 1 and not from 0.

When I do not describe what my local_item_size and have `NULL` as an argument it seems to start counting correctly from 0.

At the moment I am fixing this in my code by subtracting 1 from the return value of `get_global_id(0)` for my code to work correctly..

Shortly: When I say what my `local_item_size` is the tid starts from 1. When I give NULL it starts from 0.

Size setting code:

```
// Global item size 
if (n <= NUM_THREADS) { 
  globalItemSize = NUM_THREADS; 
  localItemSize = 16; 
} else if (n % NUM_THREADS != 0) { 
  globalItemSize = (n / NUM_THREADS + 1) * NUM_THREADS; 
} else { 
  globalItemSize = n; 
} 

// Local item size 
localItemSize = globalItemSize / NUM_THREADS;
```

Comment: What's the value of `localItemSize`/`globalItemSize`? You should probably show a little more code.

Comment: `// Global item size
        if (n <= NUM_THREADS) {
                globalItemSize = NUM_THREADS;
                localItemSize = 16;
        }
        else if (n % NUM_THREADS != 0) {
                globalItemSize = (n / NUM_THREADS + 1) * NUM_THREADS;
        }
        else {
                globalItemSize = n;
        }

        // Local item size
        localItemSize = globalItemSize / NUM_THREADS;`


NUM_THREADS is fixed at 256.

Comment: I've added the code to your question. Typically, it helps us help you when all the code is in the question and properly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The 4th parameter to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is an array of the offsets](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html), not the local size - that's the 6th parameter. Your call should be

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,
                       forceKernel, 1, 
                       NULL, &globalItemSize,
                       &localItemSize, 0, NULL, &kernelDone);
```

This is also why the IDs started at 1 - because you requested an offset of 1!

Answer (score 3):

You are passing your work-group size to the wrong argument. The third argument of `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is the global work offset, which is why your global IDs are appearing offset. The work-group size should go to the sixth argument:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,
                       forceKernel, 1, NULL,
                       &globalItemSize, &localItemSize,
                       0, NULL, &kernelDone);
```